# Drill down chart.js event click functionality

Tags: chart.js, angular8

I need drill down functionality with chart.js and angular 8. I could get a basic pie chart work and need a drill down chart now. Below is my code.

```
export class PieChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 PieChart=[];
  constructor() { }
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.pieElementRef+"VIEW initialize");
    this.PieChart = new Chart('pieElement', {
      // The type of chart we want to create
      type: 'pie',

      // The data for our dataset
      data: {
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'My First dataset',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
              data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
          }]
      },

      // Configuration options go here
      options: {
      }
  }); 
  }

  public handleClick(event) {
   // Console.log("text: "+event);
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="chart"> 
<canvas id="pieElement" (click)="handleClick($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

I could get a basic pie chart with above code. Now I want to handle click functionality to drill down child pie chart.

Comment: I completed drill down charts when clicked on title of chart. Let me know if any one need help.